# Android graphic display is not displaying complete content of my xml file

Tags: android, xml

I have developed one layout file and I want to see its preview in the android graphic display.
I'm not getting the complete content of my xml file.
It's displaying the preview upto some content of my xmlfile only.

The xml code of my layout file is is:

***main.xml code:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#850000">

        <AbsoluteLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TableLayout 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:shrinkColumns="*"  
                android:stretchColumns="*"> 

                <TableRow 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">  

                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New User Registration"/>  
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                         android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:text="Name:"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ed1"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="city"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ed2"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="gender:"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioyes"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="male" 
                        android:onClick="clickRB1"
                        android:checked="true"/>

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radiono"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="female"
                        android:onClick="clickRB2"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Date of birth:"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ed4"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Occupation:"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ed5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView06"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Category:"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ed6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView10"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Sms alert:" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_yes" 
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:onClick="clickRB9" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radio8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/radio_no" 
                        android:onClick="clickRB10"/>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Its displaying upto category only,but it's not showing  sms alert radio buttons.
Can anybody help me?

[Here you can see what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJz9V.png)

Comment: could you post a picture of what you are pursuing and what are you getting instead?

Comment: Post the whole xml layout.

Comment: ya im posting the whole xml code please check it..

Answer (score 0):

Well not enough information to work with but I suppose you should give your linear layout some width and height.

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="city"/>
                  <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ed2"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
```